# Include Helper Method to a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, view, helper

I'm new to rails and I have this small problem about helpers and controllers. Is it possible to include my custom helper to a controller?

Let's say I have this helper class.

```
Module UsersHelper
  def my_helper
    ...
  end
end
```

Then I have this controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

end
```

Can I use the **my_helper** in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - There are several ways, not least including (mixing-in) the helper into the controller, or using the loophole [explained here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2011/01/11/rails-using-helpers-inside-a-controller/)

But... if it's hard to do, or results in ugly code, it may not be the right way to do it. Can the method that's in the helper not be moved into the controller, and then delegated back to the helper using "helper_method"?

Comment: The helper method contains 'content_tag'. I think I overdo it that's why I'm having a slow benchmark results in rendering views.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can do by using `include`, but I don't recommend you doing this. Because Rails constructs under MVC architecture, you can learn more about MVC before include UserHelper in your controllers.

MVC Reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture
[Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also for the recommendation.